# ActionScript: using variable expressions w/E4X descendant accessor (..)

Tags: actionscript-3, e4x

I'm using a descendant accessor like so:

```
var myxml:XMLList = new XMLList;
```

...

```
myxml..node
```

and would like to replace it w/

```
const sNode:String = 'node';
myxml..[{sNode}]
```

This sort of thing has worked before.

```
const sAttrib:String = 'attrib';
myxml.@[{sAttrib}]
```

works, but trying the same sort of thing w/a descendant accessor causes a compiler error.

Yes, I could do

```
myxml.descendants(sNode)
```

but I'd rather do it w/operators, if I can.

The XML might be something like:

```
<map>
    <node>
       <node />
    </node>
</map>
```

Comment: Why the preference for operators? Please post an example of the XML file.

Comment: @null Because the strings I'm using are constants. I'm just of the mind that strictly using E4X w/string constants will be optimal, instead of including functions. At least, that's what an average optimizer would do. XML included.